# How do I simulate pressing keyboard shortcut with putty?

Tags: bash, command-line, cmd, putty

I am running putty through cmd and would like to write a script that simulates login, types a few commands, reads their responses and pipes the information into a text file.

I am loading a saved session to start the remote session like this:
putty.exe -load OBDII

I have a few questions:

1) I would like for putty to read a script that does the following:
simulate pressing ctrl+(3 times a) and run a few commands. I understand that there's a '-m' command that loads external files.

2) how do I write the script to simulate keyboard pressing, write and read?

Comment: Questions only? Then you're in the wrong place pal ;) Show us what you've done so far

Comment: What OS is running on the machine you log into?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but the answer is `xdotool`. 
 
For example if you want to press ctrl+(3 times a) the command would be the following :
 `xdotool key ctrl+a+a+a`
 For more information about using the tool, RTFM.

Comment: thanks! will be something I need to accomplish writing the script and commands